# How make text before ul to come in single line in html?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using [jquery li scroll plugin](http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/scrollanimate.html) in my site for creating news ticker and this jqueryli scroll plugin needs your news to be in `<li>` tag and this plugin works fine for me but the problem is that I want to put text before news ticker.

I want output like `NEWS FEED : actual news`

currently I have achieved "actual news" and when I tried to put NEWS FEED label in fron of ticker it gives my problem.

The problem is that when I put NEWS FEED label in front of ticker, the ticker news goes to the next line and I get out out as :

```
 NEWS FEED :

                                       "actual news "
```

I have used code :

```
<div>NEWS FEED
   <ul id="ticker01">
   <?php foreach ($news_array as $single_news) : ?>
   <li><span><?php echo $single_news; ?><span></li>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
   </ul>
<div>
```

How I can achieve NEWS FEED label and news ticker in single line ?

I have edited css as follows:

```
.tickercontainer { /* the outer div with the black border */


width: 850px; 
height: 32px; 
margin-left: 100px; 
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden; 
}
.tickercontainer .mask { /* that serves as a mask. so you get a sort of padding both left and right */
position: relative;
left: 10px;
top: 8px;
width: 718px;
}
ul.newsticker { /* that's your list */
position: relative;
left: 750px;
font: bold 10px Verdana;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;

}
ul.newsticker li {
float: left; /* important: display inline gives incorrect results when you check for elem's width */
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: #fff;
}
ul.newsticker a {
white-space: nowrap;
padding: 0;
color: #ff0000;
font: bold 10px Verdana;
margin: 0 50px 0 0;
} 
ul.newsticker span {
white-space: nowrap;
padding: 0;
font-family: "Times New Roman";
font-size: 16px;
color: #ff0000;
margin: 0 50px 0 0;
} 



/* liScroll styles */
```

**here is problem fiddle** : [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/p6akP/)

Comment: You can try adding 'NEWS FEED' inside a `<span>` and adding `float: left` to both?

Comment: Show your css. `jquery li scroll plugin` should already provide you this functionality. You are implementing it wrong.

Comment: I dont want NEWS FEED to be moving text rather I want it fixed.

Comment: added cutomized css in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay Done.

Works: http://jsfiddle.net/p6akP/2/

```
#outerdiv{
   float:left;
   width:1000px;
 }

.tickercontainer { /* the outer div with the black border */
     width: 850px; 
     height: 32px; 
     float:right;
     padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden; 
 }

 .tickercontainer .mask {
     top:0;
     //other styling you have
  }

 <div id="outerdiv">NEWS FEED
   <ul id="ticker01">
     <li><span>10/10/2007</span><a href="#">The first thing ...</a></li>
     <li><span>10/10/2007</span><a href="#">End up doing is ...</a></li>
     <li><span>10/10/2007</span><a href="#">The code that you ...</a></li>
   </ul>
<div>
```

Comment: Can you create fiddle link and replicate the problem ?

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/p6akP/ Your current code works ..If you have your js call after your JS librabry ...you should be good.

Comment: your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/p6akP/ is perfect example of my problem..I want to show NEWS FEED and news in single line

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41566/discussion-between-akki-and-ani)

Comment: @Akki: Done. Check out the new fiddle and answer

Answer (score 0):

`display: inline` is the way to go about it. `li` elements are block type by default. More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display